# Commutator Subgroup is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is well known that the commutator subgroup of a finitely generated nilpotent group is finitely generated, in fact all subgroups in this case are finitely generated.

I am interested in infinite groups in which the commutator subgroup is finitely generated, but not all subgroups are finitely generated. Can someone provide some class of groups which satisfy this? Thanks.

Comment: trivial comment: finitely generated perfect groups and abelian groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any finitely generated nilpotent group $H$, and $A$ to be any abelian group which is *not* finitely generated group.

Then consider $G=H\times A$. Here $G'=H'$, which is finitely generated, and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is not finitely generated.